# OpenGL ES on Android and PC

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'd like to develop a 2D game using OpenGL (ES) for self educational purpose only. The primary target architecture is Android, so the programming language will be Java I suppose (however, c/c++ is a valid competitor).

I'm wondering if is there a way to create a cross-platform solution of the OpenGL part of the program. I've checked GLSurfaceView but it seems Android only.

Is there any technique that minimizes the differences between the Android and the PC version? Does it worth the hassle at all? Where to start if it's possible? (If it's not possible, I'll be fine with the good old MVC model with different view and controller layers I guess) I don't like to use any non-standard library like libGDX (which is great) becouse I don't know OpenGL yet, and I'd like to know the basics.

Answer (score 5):

libgdx exposes the full OpenGL ES spec to you, both 1.x and 2.0. See GL10, GL11 and GL20. You don't have to use the classes build on top of that like Mesh, Texture etc. Just use it as a thin wrapper around your OS windowing system with OpenGL ES support.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is quite universal and can be ported to various platforms and languages very easily, especially if you are using java. A very good set of tutorials for using OpenGL can be found here http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm not sure what do you mean about "porting". I'll be glad if the differences could be hidden by layers and no code level tweaks would be needed. I guess it's not clear what do I mean, the linked site is currently down, I'll check it out later and get back to you. +1

Comment: porting means translate code from one type or format to another(java to c++, or pc to mac, etc)

Comment: the OpenGL tutorials in the link are in c++ thought; there aren't any good or complete OpenGL tutorials for java. I am planning to make a series on YouTube over the summer when will have time.